# Including children of children in C# Generic Repository EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am facing a slight problem and hope you could help, basically I would like to get children of children in Generic repository pattern as I have relationship table with multi-multi relationship

My Repository method looks like that:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
      var query = _entities.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
      if (includes != null)
      {
        query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
      }
      return query;
    }

public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
      return await Task.Run(() => Find(predicate, includes));
    }
```

My model:

Product:

```
public class Product : BaseEntity<long>
  {
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public int ShelfLife { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public bool HasAllergens { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductIngredient> ProductIngredient { get; set; }
  }
```

Ingredient:

```
public class Ingredient : BaseEntity<long>
  {
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductIngredient> ProductIngredient { get; set; }
  }
```

Relationship:

```
public class ProductIngredient : BaseEntity<long>
  {
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public long? ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public long? IngredientId { get; set; }
  }
```

What I'd like to achieve is to populate my ProductDto with ProductData and List of ingredients, my current ProductDto looks like:

```
public class ProductDto
    {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public DateTime CretedOn { get; set; }
      public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Barcode { get; set; }
      public int ShelfLife { get; set; }
      public int Weight { get; set; }
      public bool HasAllergens { get; set; }
      public int CustomerId { get; set; }
      public IList<IngredientDto> Ingredients { get; set; }
  }
```

I've found that I can use "ThenInclude" to include children of children, just don't know how to implement this to generic repository.

What I can do so far is just take a children then which for example I'm doing like that:

```
var results = await _productsRepository.FindAsync(p => p.Id == id, p => p.ProductIngredient);
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, the trick with `params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes` simply doesnt work with EF Core `Include` / `ThenInclude` pattern.

Comment: Yep with the intial question before editing doesn't specify the use of EF Core. You need to use the correct tag in hte future :)
@IvanStoev is right.

Comment: Right, my bad, any ideas how to do this with Generic Repo and .net core?

Comment: There is no "recommended" pattern for EF Core AFAIK. This thread [Multiple Includes() in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904414/multiple-includes-in-ef-core/43052175#43052175) might help.

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374252/how-to-write-repository-method-for-theninclude-in-ef-core-2.