# Reuse include statements in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I'm trying to make reusable includes and it currently works when I have specific concrete root entity. But let's say I have structure like this:

```
public class A
{
    public B NavigationB { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public C NavigationC { get; set; }
}

public class C
{

}
```

And my include extensions

```
public static class IncludeExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<B> MyIncludesB(this IQueryable<B> query)
    {
        return query.Include(q => q.NavigationC);
    }

    public static IQueryable<A> MyIncludesA(this IQueryable<A> query)
    {
        return query.Include(q => q.NavigationB)
            .MyIncludesB(); // how can I implement this
    }
}
```

Basically everything is okay if I have single root e.g. `A`, but what if I want to do fetch using root `B`? The idea is to then include everything required for `B`, but when using `A` as root then include everything for `A`, and when including `B`, reuse `MyIncludesB`.

I'm not sure if this is possible because include is returning `IIncludableQueryable<A, B>`, but if anyone has any suggestions, feel free to help!

Comment: You have to convert 'iqueryable<a>' to 'iqueryable<b>' to use the extension method. Does a implement b?

Comment: No, they have nothing in common, just a navigation property.

Comment: You could implement an interface, which contains the properties they have in common. and the method takes 'IQueryable<Interface>'

Comment: I'm not sure if you've understood the question correctly, but they don't have anything common. I just want to reuse standalone include within another include chain so I don't have to always copy paste all includes from `MyIncludesB` inside `MyIncludesA`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are numerous possibilities.

My first idea would be to encapsulate the property expression:

```
public static class IncludeExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<B, C>> MyIncludeListB()
    {
        return q => q.NavigationC;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<A, B>> MyIncludeListA()
    {
        return q => q.NavigationB;
    }

    public static IQueryable<B> MyIncludesB(this IQueryable<B> query)
    {
        return query.Include(MyIncludeListB());
    }

    public static IQueryable<A> MyIncludesA(this IQueryable<A> query)
    {
        return query.Include(MyIncludeListA()).ThenInclude(MyIncludeListB());
    }
}
```

As you can see you can pass `Expression<Func<B, C>>` to the method `Include`

My second idea is to implement include with strings `.Include(string)`:

```
public static class IncludeExtensions2
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> MyIncludeListB()
    {
        return "NavigationC".Split(";");
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> MyIncludeListA()
    {
        return "NavigationB;NavigationB.NavigationC".Split(";");
    }

    public static IQueryable<B> MyIncludesB(this IQueryable<B> query)
    {
        foreach (var i in MyIncludeListB())
        {
            query = query.Include(i);
        }

        return query;
    }

    public static IQueryable<A> MyIncludesA(this IQueryable<A> query)
    {
        foreach (var i in MyIncludeListA())
        {
            query = query.Include(i);
        }

        return query;
    }
}
```

As you can see you can pass `string` to the method `Include`. You can pass the complete chain of navigation properties.

If you want to implement more than one navigation property you have to amend both code examples accordingly.

There are already some questions and answers like yours:

Easy: [Entity Framework - Include Multiple Levels of Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties)

Hard: [Multiple Includes() in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904414/multiple-includes-in-ef-core)